# Send JavaScript Object from main process to renderer process to populate HTML Table Electron

Tags: javascript, electron

I am writing an inventory management application using HTML, CSS, and JavaScript with Electron. I have run into a bit of a roadblock. When I open a JSON File containing the data I want to use to populate the HTML Table in my app, the file is opened and handled processed in the main.js which is the main process of my app. What I need to do is send the processed JavaScript object to index.js (my renderer process) to be able to populate the HTML Table.

main.js:

```
const { app, BrowserWindow, Menu } = require('electron');
const { dialog } = require('electron');
const fs = require('fs');

let appWindow;
let fileContents;

function createWindow() {
    appWindow = new BrowserWindow({width: 1100, height: 769});
    appWindow.loadFile('index.html');
    appWindow.webContents.openDevTools();

    const template = 
    [
        { 
            label: 'File',
            submenu: 
            [
                {
                    label: 'Open', 
                    accelerator: 'Ctrl+O', 
                    click: () => {
                        console.log("Open was pressed!");
                        let inventoryData = dialog.showOpenDialog(appWindow, {
                            title: "Open Inventory Data", 
                            buttonLabel: "Open File",
                            filters: 
                            [
                                {
                                    name: 'JSON',
                                    extensions: ['json']
                                }
                            ],
                            properties: 
                            [ 
                                'openFile', 
                                'showHiddenFiles' 
                            ]
                        }, (filePaths, bookmarks) => {


                            filePaths.forEach((value, index, array) => {
                                fs.readFile(value, 'utf-8', (err, data) => {
                                    if(err) {
                                        throw err;
                                    }

                                    fileContents = JSON.parse(data);

                                });
                            });
                        });
                    }
                },
                {
                    label: 'Save', 
                    accelerator: 'Ctrl+S', 
                    click: () => {
                        console.log("Save was pressed!");
                    }
                },
                {
                    label: 'Merge', 
                    accelerator: 'Ctrl+M', 
                    click: () => {
                        console.log("Merge was pressed!");
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    ];

    if(process.platform === 'darwin') {
        template.unshift({
            label: 'Inventory Manager',
            submenu: 
            [
                {
                    label: 'About Inventory Manager', 
                    role: 'about'
                }, 
                {
                    type: 'separator'
                },
                {
                    label: "Quit Inventory Manager", 
                    role: 'quit'
                }
            ]
        });
    }

    const menu = Menu.buildFromTemplate(template);
    Menu.setApplicationMenu(menu);

    appWindow.on('closed', () => {
        appWindow = null;
    });
}

app.on('ready', createWindow);

app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
    if(process.platform !== 'darwin') {
        app.quit();
    }
});

app.on('activate', () => {
    if(appWindow === null) {
        createWindow();
    }
});
```

Comment: Can you separate the code for parsing the object and include that in your other process?  Just open the file again.  Otherwise you probably have to JSON.stringify the parsed object, and send it as a string through window.sendMessage ( or whatever electron recommends ).  Then JSON.parse it again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every [`MenuItem`](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/menu-item#new-menuitemoptions) has the following `click` callback signature:

```js
click(menuItem, browserWindow, event)
```

Thus, you can use `browserWindow` argument and modify the template to send data back to Renderer process using ipc or directly run js in html:

```js
...
label: 'Open', 
accelerator: 'Ctrl+O', 
click: (menuItem, browserWindow, event) => {
    let inventoryData = dialog.showOpenDialog(appWindow, {
      ...
    }, (filePaths, bookmarks) => {
      ...
      fileContents = JSON.parse(data)
      // #1 ipc (recommended)
      browserWindow.webContents.send('populate-table', fileContents)
      // #2 execute js
      browserWindow.webContents.executeJavaScript(`
        document.populateTable(fileContents) // whatever u have
      `)
    });
}
...
```

Comment: when my app launches, i want to use `preload.js` to populate a table in a secondary or non-index html page, but obvs `preload.js` does not seem to have access to it. do u know how i would go about this or if this is even the appropriate way to do things? in other words, `index.html` has links that point to other `.html` files; it is one of these other `.html` files that has a `table` that i would like to populate before ever even navigating to that `.html` page from `index.hmtl`